# Fastest method to get current location with Google Location Services

Tags: android, android-location

Hi i was wondering which of these settings would return a location the quickest using Google Location Services:

1. ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION with PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
2. ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION with PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY
3. ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION with PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY
4. ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION with PRIORITY_LOW_POWER

my theories are that a finer search would take longer, while lower accuracy might be faster.